# Random matrix fill between 1 and 0 in java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to fill randomly a two-dimensional int array with just 0's and 1's this is the method i'm using to fill my array

```
   private void buildMaze(){
           maze=new int[this.mazeSize][this.mazeSize];
       for(int i=0;i<this.mazeSize;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<this.mazeSize;j++){
                this.maze[i][j]=r.nextInt(2)-1;    
            }
        }
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that everytime that i run my tests i get something like this:

```
| -1 ||  0 ||  0  |
|  0 || -1 || -1  |
|  0 || -1 || -1  |
```

My question here is: How could i fill the array correctly with random values ​​between 0 and 1?

Comment: You might want to show your declaration and initialization for r (the random number generator).

Comment: you might want to use Math.random() instead of Random class Math.random generates random numbers between 0 to 1 then explicitly cast it to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Random.nextInt(int bound)` method return int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive). For your case It's returning value between 0 to 1, but you subtract 1 from that. So when this method return 0, you subtract 1, so It's giving you -1.

Update your code Like the below one :

```
this.maze[i][j]=r.nextInt(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), you might consider using [`nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--) (it won't consume entropy as quickly). And you might also use a [`for-each` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

```
private void buildMaze() {
    maze = new int[this.mazeSize][this.mazeSize];
    for (int[] row : maze) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            row[j] = r.nextBoolean() ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Your current method `r.nextInt(2)-1;` generates either `0` or `1` and then subtracts one yielding the range `-1, 0`. You could also write

```
private void buildMaze() {
    maze = new int[this.mazeSize][this.mazeSize];
    for (int[] row : maze) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            row[j] = r.nextInt(2); // <-- 0 (inclusive) to 2 (exclusive)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it might be good to also explain why OP code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
Math.random()
```

Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0

```
            double j=Math.random();
            j=(j>0.5)?1:0;
```